How to make nested CSS flex child grow and shrink based on available space, regardless of own content?
I have a parent flexbox of constrained width (in this example, 500px) with some content, including a child flexbox. I need some flexbox children (ones assigned flex-fill in the snippet) to fill all available space, but not grow beyond the width allowed by the parent. So the parent element should never be wider than 500px, regardless of any content nested inside.
However, with my current CSS, when the child flexbox has content that is wider than the maximum allowed space, it keeps growing, with no respect to that boundary (despite flex-shrink: 1 and overflow: hidden). How can this be fixed?


.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-fill {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.first-level-child {      
  /* for demonstrating its size easily */
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.second-level-child {
  /* I was assuming this will clip long text? */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
}

p {
  /* to make sure it has large width */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="parent flex">
  <div> <p>Some content</p> </div>
  
  <div class="first-level-child flex flex-fill">
    <div class="second-level-child flex-fill">
      <!--<p>If short content, all good.</p>-->
      <p>If there is very long text here, the first and second level children end up growing. This is not good: the parent div of this text should not care, and always take just the allowed space.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div> <p>Other content<p> </div>
  </div>
  
  <div> <p> Etc... </p> </div>
</div>



Note: The problem is similar to the one in this question, but the solution doesn't apply as the content is nested.
Note 2 for duplication claim: This question is not a duplicate of this. For one, because, as already stated in the first note, the content is nested, while in that question, it is not. For two, the correct answer to that question of setting overflow: hidden is already set in my snippet.

min-width: 0 to .first-level-child

so you say "thank you" and at the same time, it's not a duplicate .. I have closed the question as duplicate so please "read carefully" before claiming it's not duplicate

@TemaniAfif The question is not a duplicate, but the answer to a different question somewhat touches on the solution ("may be necessary" is a bit vague though). But matters not, my issue is fixed, I hope it helps that this question is here for people searching in similar terms as I was, which didn't show that other question. Have a good day!
